# Display byte as unsigned

Tags: java, android, opencv, byte, unsigned

I'm building an Android app using OpenCV4Android. For manipulating some images I work with (i.e `Mat` objects), I convert them into a `byte[]` (using the `get` method). My problem is that the values of this array appear as unsigned bytes, which makes it really hard to debug:
[image]

Is there a way to overcome this and display the array's values as unsigned bytes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java does not supply an unsigned byte primitive. For debugging purposes, you could copy each byte to an int[] (being sure to avoid negative values) and view the int[]. That's a kludge, but that's about the closest solution.

Simply assigning byte to int will preserve the sign, and so will using a cast. Use

```
int myInt = myByte & 0xFF;
```

Comment: thanks. what do you mean by "being sure to avoid negative values"? isn't it depends on whether I look at the variable as signed or unsigned? specifically for my case, the bytes have values between -128 to 127 (if I remember correctly...)

Comment: Ok, saw you edited your post. now it is clear, and more important - it's working. I don't really like it, but as a workaround it's fine... thanks